# How does llvm's SDUse works?

Tags: llvm

I'm reading llc's code about SDUse,I cannot understand SDUse::addToList(SDUse **List).
How does its **pre and *next works to insert a node in a list?

```
 /// Represents a use of a SDNode. This class holds an SDValue,
 /// which records the SDNode being used and the result number, a
 /// pointer to the SDNode using the value, and Next and Prev pointers,
 /// which link together all the uses of an SDNode.
 ///
 class SDUse {
   /// Val - The value being used.
   SDValue Val;
   /// User - The user of this value.
   SDNode *User = nullptr;
   /// Prev, Next - Pointers to the uses list of the SDNode referred by
   /// this operand.
   SDUse **Prev = nullptr;
   SDUse *Next = nullptr;
```

.....

```
   void addToList(SDUse **List) {
     Next = *List;
     if (Next) Next->Prev = &Next;
     Prev = List;
     *List = this;
   }
  
   void removeFromList() {
     *Prev = Next;
     if (Next) Next->Prev = Prev;
   }
 };
```

Comment: It's just a regular linked list, the way it's usually written in C. That idiom is a bit unusual for C++, that's all.

Comment: I know it's a doubly linked list, and it's quick in remove a node in list. But I can not understand how is the node added to the list. Especially "Pre = List". func "addToList" insert the node before *list.

Comment: There's a pointer to the head somewhere, and a pointer to the next node in each node. `Prev` is a pointer to either of those, and `*Prev = …` either inserts a new first node or inserts a new subsequent node.